# non-ascii char as arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

printargv.js:

```
console.log(Buffer.byteLength(process.argv[2]));
```

In cmd.exe (with chcp=65001,font='Lucida Console'), I ran:

```
node printargv.js Ā
```

(Note: unicode code point of Ā is U+0100.) The script outputted:

> 1

I expected the script to print a number greater than 1 but it doesn't. Does anyone know why?

edit:
i think that node 'parses' initial arguments incorrectly for cmd.exe after i tried the below code:

```
var i = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin,process.stdout);

i.question('char: ', function(c){
  console.log( Buffer.byteLength(c) );
  i.close();
  process.stdin.destroy();
});
```

the output is 2

Comment: @Juhana: The question is, more or less, "why does it print 1 when it should print 2?".

Comment: I get 2 on Ubuntu using UTF-8 in the terminal. If I output the char code of the character, I get the correct value (256). (Try outputting `process.argv[2].charCodeAt(0)`.) I can only assume there's some issue with [Lucida Console](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1262) (note from that page that it doesn't claim to support codepage 65001), which like most fonts has incomplete Unicode support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not receiving the `Ā`, it's receiving an `A` instead. I used this program to test:

```
var n;
for (n = 0; n < process.argv.length; ++n) {
    console.log(n + ": '" + process.argv[n] + "'");
}
console.log("length: " + process.argv[2].length);
console.log("code: " + process.argv[2].charCodeAt(0));
console.log("size: " + Buffer.byteLength(process.argv[2]));
```

On Ubuntu using UTF-8 in the console, I got:

```
$ node test.js Ā
0: 'node'
1: '/home/tjc/temp/test.js'
2: 'Ā'
length: 1
code: 256
size: 2
```

...which is correct.

On Windows 7 using `chcp 65001` and Lucida Console, I got:

```
C:\tmp>node temp.js Ā
0: 'node'
1: 'C:\tmp\temp.js'
2: 'A'
length: 1
code: 65
size: 1
```

Note that the `Ā` became an `A` at some point along the way.

As I said in my comment on the question, I can only assume there's some issue with [Lucida Console](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1262), or cmd.exe's handling of UTF-8, or perhaps `node.exe`'s handling of Unicode from the console on Windows (I used the [pre-built 0.5.7 version](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.5.7/node.exe)).

---

**Update**: This might be something to take up with the NodeJS folks, since Windows appears to get it right on its own. If I put this code in a `test.vbs` file:

```
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Echo AscW(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

I get a correct result:

```
C:\tmp>cscript /nologo test.vbs Ā
Ā
256
```

...suggesting that the terminal is passing the argument correctly to the program. So it could be an issue with the Windows `node.exe` build.

Comment: To avoid swap between latin chars, I tried another set of chars which codepage greater than 0x024f(the end of latin-extend-b), e.g. CJK Ideograph 1(from 0x4e00), the output is still wrong.

Comment: @user943702: I think this is something to take up with the NodeJS folks, see the update above.

Comment: I did the same thing(using cscript and java)before. It produces correct output in same cmd.exe(setting with 65001, lucida console). it is mostly the issue with node.exe(2011.09.16 v0.5.7 (unstable))